# UserForm vbmodeless

Tags: vba

How can I keep a Userform in modeless on top and update the text while operation is running? I am trying to my UserForm on top while operation is running and update the text on the UserForm as module works through different sections. The form gets pushed to the background by the continuing routine and you can't read it until the routine is finished and I change the text to "Scan completed".

Ex:

```
With Notice
.caption = "Gain/Loss Tables"
.text = "Starting the scans"
.show vbmodeless
end with
```

At certain points I wish to update the text to indicate progress

```
with Notice
.text = "Starting scan for new members"
.show vbmodeless
end with
```

I would appreciate any suggestions

Sincerely,

Hobart Gay

I have attempted using Timevalue delays of 2-3 seconds to allow the update with no success.

Comment: Tricky. I'd say show the form modal and let the form begin the process. To update, set the text followed by `DoEvents` - not much you can do there (single thread).

Comment: Thank you. that seems to work. I appreciate the quick response and the good advice.